# JDBC spring datasource declaration

Tags: java, spring, jdbc

Why doesn't this work (throws exception: `Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'`)?

```
public class Test {

    public static BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();

    public Test() {
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUsername("root");
        dataSource.setPassword("");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost/database");
        dataSource.setMaxActive(10);
        dataSource.setMaxIdle(5);
        dataSource.setInitialSize(5);
        dataSource.setValidationQuery("SELECT 1");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        SqlRowSet rs = jdbcTemplate.queryForRowSet("SELECT * FROM table");
    }

}
```

But this does work

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUsername("root");
        dataSource.setPassword("");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost/database");
        dataSource.setMaxActive(10);
        dataSource.setMaxIdle(5);
        dataSource.setInitialSize(5);
        dataSource.setValidationQuery("SELECT 1");

        JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        SqlRowSet rs = jdbcTemplate.queryForRowSet("SELECT * FROM table");
    }

}
```

Why can't I initiate dataSource in the constructor once and use it throughout methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    SqlRowSet rs = jdbcTemplate.queryForRowSet("SELECT * FROM table");
}
```

doesn't call your constructor. It's a *static* method in the `Test` class and as such is purely namespaced. No instance of `Test` is created, and hence your datasource code doesn't run.

Comment: So how to I call the constructor in this case?